# TEST : Http Callout Error

Tags: apex, unit-test, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I was  trying to test an apex class that uses some http callouts with HTTPMockRequest. When trying to run the Test class it gives me the following error:

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

This is my Test class

```
@isTest()
public class retrieveGAdata_Test {


public static final string sDate = 'yesterday'; 
public static final string eDate = 'today'; 



  public static testmethod  void testsaveDataToSF()
  {

   retrieveGaData test1 = new retrieveGAdata();

     SingleRequestMock fakeAccountResp = new SingleRequestMock(200,
                                                     'Complete',
                                                     '[{"Name": "sForceTest1"}]',
                                                     null);

    SingleRequestMock fakeContactsResp = new SingleRequestMock(200,
                                              'Complete',
                                              '[{"LastName": "Test Last Name"}]',
                                               null);

    Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> endpoint2TestResp =
                               new Map<String,HttpCalloutMock>();
    endpoint2TestResp.put('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',fakeAccountResp);
    endpoint2TestResp.put('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/',fakeContactsResp);

    HttpCalloutMock multiCalloutMock =
                               new MultiRequestMock(endpoint2TestResp);

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiCalloutMock);

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `retrieveGaData test1 = new retrieveGAdata();` *after* `Test.setMock`. That's the only line of code that could execute a callout as far as I can see.

```
public static testmethod  void testsaveDataToSF()
{
    // other setup
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiCalloutMock);
    retrieveGaData test1 = new retrieveGAdata();
}
```